# How much does extending affect range of focusing distances?

Tags: macro, extension-tubes, focus-distance, calculations

It's well known that moving a lens away from imaging surface will decrease both minimum and maximum focusing distance. There are times when it would be good to know *how much* those distances will change.

Is there a formula to estimate the range of available focusing distances (i.e. minimum and maximum focusing distance) with a given lens after adding an extension tube (or stretching a bellows)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the change an extension tube makes to the maximum magnfication of a lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9888/how-can-i-calculate-the-change-an-extension-tube-makes-to-the-maximum-magnficati)

Answer (score 1):

For minimum distance calculations, see here for details: http://photo.net/large-format-photography-forum/00Sswe

Extract:

"The core formula [for minimum focus distance] is 1 / f = 1 / u + 1 / v

Where f is the focal length of the lens, u is lens to subject distance, and v is lens to film distance.

More properly, v and u are measured from the focal point of the lens. For a symmetric lens, that's usually smack-dab in the middle of the lens. For a telephoto lens, it's way in front of the lens -- that's the definition of telephoto. For a retrofocus lens, it's way behind the lens.

Magnification is v / u."

[add your extension tube length to 'v' to see how the range changes.]

More calcs of all kinds here: http://photo.net/learn/optics/lensTutorial#part1