# What kind of bellows should I use for 5x magnification with a 100mm lens?

Tags: macro, magnification, bellows

I have a Canon 1200D and I have a Tokina f2.8 100mm macro lens. I would like to achieve up to 5x magnification.  Which bellows should I use?

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Are you looking for a specific product recommendation? A minimum length recommendation?

Comment: A very long one.

Comment: See [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/how-can-i-calculate-what-the-effect-of-an-extension-tube-will-be#5629). And you'll understand that you should better use a shorter lens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate what the effect of an extension tube will be?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/how-can-i-calculate-what-the-effect-of-an-extension-tube-will-be)

Answer (score 3):

Using this [Extension Calculator](https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/macro-extension-tubes-closeup.htm) it looks like it may be difficult to find a bellows with the amount of extension you need.

To achieve 5:1 magnification with a 100mm lens, you need to have a lens extension of approx 400mm or 15 inches.

You will also need a bellows that has electrical contacts so that you can control the aperture on your Tamron lens. Bellows without electrical contacts are much cheaper, but next to impossible to use, since there is no way to control the aperture on modern AF lenses.

This [$759 Novoflex Bellows for Canon EOS](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/197081-REG/Novoflex_BALCAN_AF_Auto_Bellows_for_Canon.html)  has a maximum extension of 5.12 inches and would only allow approx 2.3x magnification with your 100mm lens.

[image]

If you really need 5x magnification, your best bet is probably the  [$1,049 Canon MP-E 65mm 1-5x Macro](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/183199-USA/Canon_2540A002_Macro_Photo_MP_E_65mm.html).

[image]

Comment: To take a 100mm 1:1 lens to 5:1, the bellows pictured will not be long enough, even at full extension.

Comment: Cascading two bellows (or adding extension rings)?

Comment: Will i get an adapter for the tokina 100mm to be used with this ? If so which one?

Comment: There is no need for an adapter if you get a bellows with the Canon EF mount. https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/197081-REG/Novoflex_BALCAN_AF_Auto_Bellows_for_Canon.html

Comment: Just using the calculator... a Canon APS-C sensor has a diagonal of roughly 27mm.  With a 100mm lens, the native magnification is about 3.7x (at 1:1 scale macro but this *assumes* no lens breathing and a true 100mm focal length).  A 5" bellows (127mm extension) would take that to 4.97x.  Based on this, it seems like the Novoflex bellows *just* get you to the 5x.  The Canon MP-E 65mm certainly would.

Comment: The bellows above will give 5:1 if you use a shorter lens.  Something like a 50mm or even 35mm will give 5:1 in half or roughly a third the extension -- of course, you'll also need the subject to be similarly closer to the front element...