# Can you turn a 60mm macro lens into a 100mm macro lens?

Tags: canon, macro, teleconverter

I have a Canon EF-S 60mm Macro lens.

Can I add an extension tube or teleconverter to emulate a 100mm Macro?

If not, is there a solution?

Comment: "If not, is there a solution?" We don't know, what actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: As in the question can I add an extension tube or teleconverter to a 60mm macro to emulate a 100mm macro?

Comment: Why not just crop the image to your desired field of view?

Comment: @StephenJ That's not a problem, that's a solution to a problem. How is turning a 60mm macro lens into a 100mm macro lens going to improve your photography?

Comment: More a technical question rather than an artistic question because I can’t find it anywhere on the internet. If I add an extension tube, say, does a 60mm macro act like a 120mm or 30mm macro?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate what the effect of an extension tube will be?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/how-can-i-calculate-what-the-effect-of-an-extension-tube-will-be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I add an extension tube [to a 60mm macro lens]...to emulate a 100mm Macro?

No, but you can add an extension tube to a 100mm lens to let you focus closer, just like a 100mm macro lens.

Answer (score 4):

No, an extension tube doesn't really increase the focal length of your lens, it just allows it to focus on closer subjects.

Assuming you want to shoot subjects farther away than with the 60mm, to turn your 60mm into a 100m, you would need either:

- a teleconverter/tele-extender) (a lens that that goes between the lens and the camera): extenders are rarely compatible with short focal lengths, the good ones are are pricey and are really designed for prime telephoto lenses. And these lenses are also designed to work with extenders...
- a teleside converter/telephoto conversion lens (a lens that mounts like a filter on the front element). Assuming you find one of decent quality, it could still produce very soft pictures when focusing in the "macro" range.

The real question is whether the resulting definition of your pictures is still the same. If you get a 2px blur/softness, you are better off cropping the picture from the plain 60mm.

The non-IS Canon 100mm is easily found on the second-hand market. Tamron and Sigma also have very good macro lenses in the 90-110mm range

Comment: Thanks...gave me the info I needed. Cheers

Comment: Doubt a macro lens with a teleconverter will be better than just using a sufficiently close-focusing, garden variety telephoto or even telezoom lens without a teleconverter...

Comment: @xenoid your definitions of extender and teleconverter are not correct. "Extender" is just Canon's wording for "teleconverter". While there are also teleconverters that can mount on a front of a lens, they are generally inferior to rear mount teleconverters.

Comment: "teleconverter" seems to apply to both sides of the lens, which is why I went Ĉanon's way to remove some ambiguity, and why I added a definition... If you have better, generally accepted, unambiguous designations, I'll edit my post.

Comment: For what it's worth (often but not always a reasonable reflection of "generally accepted"), Wikipedia uses [teleconverter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleconverter) ("sometimes called a tele extender") for the between-camera-and-lens type, and [teleside converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleside_converter) (or " telephoto conversion lens or front mount teleconverter") for the thing that screws on the front.

Comment: Since Nikon, Pentax, Fujifilm, and Olympus (just the ones I checked offhand) use telecoverter for what Canon calls "extender", I think Canon is really the odd one out. I would _at least_ note that you're using Canon's terminology for the first term, and probably _not_ use "teleconverter" for the second.

Comment: OK, vocabulary changed.

Comment: Canon calls them 'Extenders' because the elements of the teleconverter actually extend into the back of the lens. That's why Canon's extenders are only compatible with certain lenses. There needs to be enough room in the back of the lens to allow the extender to extend past the flange and into the rear fo the lens.